# Grouping an SQL search without looping within in each loop - is there a better way?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database of pupils from which I want to group each pupil according to their form class. At the moment I can only do this by looping within each group. Is there a better way to do this. What I want the results to look like is this:

- Year 1

  - Form Class 1

    - Pupil Y, Pupil , Pupil K
  - Form Class 2

    - Pupil G, Pupil A, Pupil Z
- Year 2

  - Form Class 3

    - Pupil A, Pupil U, Pupil Q
  - Form Class 4

    - Pupil V, Pupil R, Pupil M
- Year 3

  - Form Class 5

    - Pupil G, Pupil S, Pupil D
  - Form Class 6

    - Pupil W, Pupil P, Pupil C

The database looks like this:

```
+----+------+----------+-------+
|Year|Class |First Name|Surname|
+----+------+----------+-------+
|1   |Class3|Jenny     |James  | 
|1   |Class1|John      |Bruces |  
|1   |Class1|Dirk      |Diggler|
|1   |Class2|Michael   |Johnson|
+----+------+----------+-------+
```

The coding I have tried so far is:

```
<?php
$pupil_details = $_SESSION['pupdetails'];
$selectclass   = $connect->query("SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM `$pupil_details` ORDER BY class DESC");

while ($rows = $selectclass->fetch_array()) {                
    echo $rows["Year"];
    $yrlvl = $rows['Year'];
?><br/><?php              
    $selectpup = $connect->query("SELECT DISTINCT class from `$pupil_details` where Year ='$yrlvl'");

    while ($rowsd = $selectpup->fetch_array()) {
        $yrlvlclass = $rowsd['class'];
        echo $yrlvlclass;
?><br/><?php        
        $wholeSchool = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from $pupil_details where class ='$yrlvlclass' ORDER BY surname asc");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($wholeSchool)) {
            echo $row["firstname"];
            echo $row["surname"];                                          
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Can anybody suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: can you post the database schema?

Comment: the use of database object name in sql is not allowed .. are you sure your query are valid in php???

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Comment: The code I posted above does work but I am looking for a more efficient way than having to create searches within each loop. I had read it might be possible with changing the way the array is presented but I can't figure out how to do this. I essentially want each year level with each class in that year level below it, with each pupil underneath the form class they are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and it worked:

```
$selectPupil   = $connect->query("select  *  from  `pupils` order by Year, Class, Surname");

$neededForFirstValue = 0;

while ($row = $selectPupil->fetch_array()) { 
    //set initial values for year
    if($neededForFirstValue == 0) {
        $previousYear = $row['Year']; //takes the value to compare
        echo "Year " . $previousYear . "<br />"; //display first year
        $neededForFirstValue = 1; //to never go into that if again
    }
    $currentYear = $row['Year']; //takes current year value

    if($currentYear == $previousYear) { //check if year has changed, if not, keep going
        //set initial values for class
        if($neededForFirstValue == 1) {
            $previousClass = $row['Class']; //takes the value to compare
            echo "Class: " . $previousClass . "<br />"; //display first year
            $neededForFirstValue = 2; //to never go into any if again
        }
        $currentClass = $row['Class'];
        if($currentClass == $previousClass) {
            echo $row['First Name'] . " " . $row['Surname'] . "<br />"; //display a pupil
        } else {
            echo "Class: " . $currentClass . "<br />"; //display current year
            echo $row['First Name'] . " " . $row['Surname'] . "<br />"; //display first user in each class
        }
    } else {
        echo "Year " . $currentYear . "<br />"; //display current year
    }
    $previousClass = $row['Class']; //remember the year to compare
    $previousYear = $row['Year']; //remember the year to compare
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do all with a single query simply ordering by year, class and surname

```
 select  * 
 from  your_table 
 order by Year, class, surname
```

but don't use var inside your php code  .. you are at risk for sql injection .. and in your case the use of object (table name) in var in alos not allowed  in SQL

Comment: Thanks for sorting them in the correct order. I am looking to present this information on the page so that that each class has a heading(the class name) and then the pupils in that class underneath?

Comment: check for value change in your loop  ..and when change set the header you need

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to all this. Can you put a code example to show how to do this?